# Target a label element with no selectors using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So the html looks like this

```
<div class="col-12">
<label>Enter your post code <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_zipbox" name="custom[map-zip]" value="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

And I am trying to access the label and replace the text.

The col-12 selector is not unique, so I have been trying to target the input with the id.

I've tried the following

```
e = document.getElementById("form_zipbox");
e.closest("label"); // returns null
e.closet("div > childElement"); // null. As does child, childNode, just for sake of trying.
```

How can I access the label.

```
e.closest("div"); // Does return col-12 obviously
```

Just can't get a hold of this label. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Btw, it needs to be vanilla js, not jquery. Thanks

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) using `closest('div')` to get the label only. Using pure `JavaScript`

```js
let e = document.getElementById("form_zipbox");
let div = e.closest("div").firstElementChild;
console.log(div)
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Enter your post code <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_zipbox" name="custom[map-zip]" value="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

You can also target directly at the label using [previousElementSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp) of the input.

```js
let e = document.getElementById("form_zipbox");
console.log(e.previousElementSibling)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Enter your post code <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_zipbox" name="custom[map-zip]" value="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it have been easier to simple set `id` to `label`? I wonder why he doesn't want so!

Comment: @Sapinder It would normally yes - but Thats what this question is for. "Get labels with no selectors"

Comment: @Sapinder Because situations don't always allow us. FYI, this is a wordpress theme, that's the reason.

Comment: @dylzee I haven't used Wordpress. That's what made me think.Thanks anyway!